# Macos partition delete and merge

Tags: linux, macos, macintosh, apple

Macos montenery 12.3 - Air 2020

I ve tryed to install asahi linux from this: https://asahilinux.org/2022/03/asahi-linux-alpha-release/

I created a 70gb partition in the installer for it, but network was down so the installation was canceled.

**Now i have to delete these partitions and i cant.**

Ive tryed to delete it via the gui tool and via the diskutils:

- diskutils error: Error: -69488: This operation does not support the input of an APFS Container disk
- diskutils list:

> ```
> marci@PerecBook-Air-13-M1-2020 ~ % diskutil list
> /dev/disk0 (internal):
>    #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
>    0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         251.0 GB   disk0
>    1:             Apple_APFS_ISC                         524.3 MB   disk0s1
>    2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         171.6 GB   disk0s2
>    3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk4         2.5 GB     disk0s5
>    4:                        EFI EFI - ASAHI             500.2 MB   disk0s4
>    5:           Linux Filesystem                         70.5 GB    disk0s7
>    6:        Apple_APFS_Recovery                         5.4 GB     disk0s3
>
> /dev/disk3 (synthesized):
>    #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
>    0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +171.6 GB   disk3
>                                  Physical Store disk0s2
>    1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            15.2 GB    disk3s1
>    2:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 15.2 GB    disk3s1s1
>    3:                APFS Volume Preboot                 504.6 MB   disk3s2
>    4:                APFS Volume Recovery                798.2 MB   disk3s3
>    5:                APFS Volume Data                    50.8 GB    disk3s5
>    6:                APFS Volume VM                      3.2 GB     disk3s6
>
> /dev/disk4 (synthesized):
>    #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
>    0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +2.5 GB     disk4
>                                  Physical Store disk0s5
>    1:                APFS Volume Asahi                   815.1 KB   disk4s1
>     enter code here
> ```

I ve tired with this article:
https://www.ithinkdiff.com/fix-partition-issues-in-mac-os-x-when-disk-utility-doesnt-help/

**How can i delete the "asahi" partition and linux filesystem. Then merge it to the mac partition**?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the same happened to me

I just followed a YouTube video and it worked fine.

link: https://youtu.be/nMnWTq2H-N0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/412042)